# Jquery scroll down instantly to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little chat app going on. I would like to scroll down to the first unread message. This is what I have:

```
for i in data.conversation
 $('#chatBox').append("<div class='rrr'>i.message + "-" + i.read</div>")
```

`data.conversation` is an object that has a message and a read value. How do I scroll `#chatBox` all the way down to where `i.read` equals `unread`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate IMHO... Here the element to scroll to is not clearly defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's scrollIntoView() function. For example:

```
$(".rrr").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

In your situation, I think you simply need to give each element in the chatbox an attribute depending on whether i.read equals to true or not. I don't know the rest of your code, but I imagine it would look something like this.

```
for i in data.conversation
 let msg = $("<div class='rrr'>" + i.message + "</div>");
 if(!(i.read)) {
   msg.attr("class", "unread");
 }
 $('#chatBox').append(msg);

$(".unread").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to "identify" wich element to scroll to.
for example, adding a "class" for read/unread:

```
$('#chatBox').append("<div class='rrr status-" + i.read + "'>i.message + "</div>")
```

So you can "target" it to scroll there after the loop:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".status-unread").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Check the "possible duplicate" for more information about scrolling.

EDIT:
...check this answer also, it's even closer to you case: [jquery Scroll to class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390205/jquery-scroll-to-class-name)

If you want it to be "inmediate" just change the animation time (2000) to 0... or something much shorter than 2 seconds but still comfortable for the user.